# How to display number of rows with only lower case characters

Tags: python, web-applications

How to display number of rows with only lower case characters using pandas

Comment: [pandas.Series.str.islower](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.islower.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have made it for you:

```
 def get_lowercase(self):
"""
Return number of rows with only lower case characters for selected column
"""
    if self.serie.str.islower():
        lower = self.serie.str
        lower = lower.to_frame()
        return lower[self.col_name].values.sum()
```